# Static Content is not loading after upgrade

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-2.1.3, 404, static-content

After upgrade from the Magento 2.1.0 to the Magento 2.1.3 (using composer) static content is not loading anymore. In the browser console I can see that all files is unavailable (404):

[image: files unavailable preview]

I don't see directories with the name `version*` in the `pub` directory.

What I already made but it didn't help:

1. set all permissions to `777`, but without success.
2. cleaned cache
3. removed the `pub/static/*`
4. regenerated static content few times
5. replaced the `.htaccess` file (in the `pub/static` directory) with the file from an official repository.

Another info:

- `mod_rewrite` is enabled
- `FollowSymLinks` is allowed (in the default host configuration and local `.htaccess`)
- This configuration worked fine with Magento 2.1.0 before the updating to the 2.1.3
- `pub/static` is writable

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you redeploy static content?

Comment: Yes, I did it many times without success

Comment: I'm having the same issue, upvoted. In my case I'm using Nginx and the same conf files. Updating was done using composer, and did the same steps as @SiarheyUchukhlebau did

Comment: Oh dear. Suddenly got the same problem, but using Apache. Clearing pub/static set it off and I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: May have found a solution below.

Comment: Can anyone help me to make this platform work?
I installed it several times using various methods but I have not yet managed to make it work. First I had the same problem as the one presented at the very beginning of this thread.
After I have gone through all the instructions on this page I made the changes to htaccess in /pub/static : <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /pub/static RewriteRule ^version.+?/(.+)$ $1 [L] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l RewriteRule .* ../static.php?resource=$0 [L] </IfModule> and added the code line to the

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The main issue was caused by the incorrect rewrites work ( as @Marius told ). There was no **`RewriteBase`**  in my directory  `pub/static/` and Apache could not find the files because searched for them from the root folder.  After we’ve added: `RewriteBase /pub/static` everything start working.

How it worked:

by this address:

> http://m2.uchuhlebov.web.ra/pub/static/version1481885888/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js

the rewrite should work:

```
RewriteRule ^version.+?/(.+)$ $1 [L]
```

as the line started from the root folder:

```
/pub/static/version...
```

it hasn’t worked and could not redirect to the file, needed.

Rewrite without base:

[image: rewrite doesnt work]

Rewrite with base:

[image: rewrite works]

Here a part of my `.htaccess` file from the `pub/static` (rewrites) :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /pub/static
    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    RewriteRule ^version.+?/(.+)$ $1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule .* ../static.php?resource=$0 [L]
</IfModule>
```

#### How to disable static-files versioning:

If you do not want to use static files versioning you can disable this feature in the Magento admin area:

[image: config]

It is possible to change this setting for default scope using the following **MySQL query**:

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data`(`path`, `value`) VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value`=0
```

Then execute next command to clear a configuration cache:

```
bin/magento cache:clean config
```

**PS:** My answer is actual for the apache2 users. If you are using **NGINX** see [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/150532/37497) (by @kevin-javitz)

Comment: if `dev/static/sign` in exists then insert it. `INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', '0')`

Comment: On apache2 systems, you need to enable mod_rewrite with:- `sudo a2enmod rewrite`.

Answer (score 9):

If you are running Nginx, here is the fix. You probably have your own conf file, you need to update the /static/ part with this, they have updated part of it specifically:  # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache section:

```
location /static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}
```

Comment: Additional note, if you are using apache make sure you have this in your pub/static/.htaccess line 16:
`RewriteRule ^version.+?/(.+)$ $1 [L]`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it pointed me to the correct solution of the issue. I use Apache and the solution is different, but i’m grateful to you anyway.

Comment: You are a life safer! I was banging mu head against the wall! Can confirm it work for my nginx Magento 2.1.3

Answer (score 7):

Go to the database and insert a row in core_config_data table:

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', '0');
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

There shouldn't be a `version*` folder in the `static` folder.
This most probably happens because you don't have mod_rewrite enabled in your instance.
The path `pub/static/version1234/some/asset.js` should be rewritten to `pub/static/some/asset.js`. The version thing is there only for browser cache expiration.

Comment: I check `mod_rewrite`  and it is enabled: `[root@web www]# httpd -M | grep "rewrite"
 rewrite_module (shared)
Syntax OK` in the .htaacess it is enabled too

Comment: make sure that `FollowSymLinks` is allowed. This happened to me after installing the latest version from github and I had a problem with the mod_rewrite and with the FollowSymLinks.

Comment: In the rewrite section `FollowSymLinks` is set as `Options +FollowSymLinks` and there was no problem with the same configuration before up-dating :(

Answer (score 4):

It seems like the 2.1.3 release assumes the default value for 
`Stores => Configuration => Developer => Static Files Settings => Sign Static Files` is set to Yes.

So instead of changing the rewrites, its possible to set this feature to No.

If it's not possible to do this from the admin, because the admin fails to load the frontend assets, change/add this setting in the `core_config_data` table:

> scope: default
>   scope_id: 0
>   path: dev/static/sign
>   value: 0

This issue is also noted on Github: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7869

Answer (score 3):

If you're using apache. You mustn't delete the .htaccess from pub/static. You can get a replacement [here.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/2.1/pub/static/.htaccess)

Comment: Thank you. I have already replaced that file, but issue was in the incorrect `RewriteBase`.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command with 1 for "Yes" and 0 for "No"

```
 bin/magento config:set dev/static/sign 1
```