# Magento 2: CSS & JS not found (404)

Tags: magento2, javascript, css, 404

I recently encoutered a strage mangento2 behaviour which I cant fix...
Everytime i try to load my store (frontend & backend) I get `404 errors` on every `.css` `.js` `.svg` and so on.

I tried:

• `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

• `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

• `php bin/magento cache:flush`

• `php bin/magento cache:clear`

After checking the directory I saw that I don't got a `version<numberhere>`-directory. Everything is just placed in the `pub/static` folder and not `pub/static/version<numberhere>`.

Thanks in adivce.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau OP doesn't state this is M2 2.1.3

Answer (score 5):

Most likely the rewrite-module doesn't work at yours web server or you have specified incorrect rewrite settings in the `pub/static/.htaccess` file. Try to change rewrite base to the:

```
/pub/static
```

The rewrite section should look like this (apache):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /pub/static
    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    RewriteRule ^version.+?/(.+)$ $1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule .* ../static.php?resource=$0 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If you do not want to use static files versioning you can disable this feature in the Magento admin area:

[image: config]

It is possible to change this setting for default scope using the following **MySQL query**:

```
INSERT INTO 'core_config_data' ('path', 'value') 
    VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;
```

Then execute next command to clear a configuration cache:

```
bin/magento cache:clean config
```

[In this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150418/static-content-is-not-loading-after-upgrade-to-2-1-3) you can find additional information and configuration file for the Nginx.

Comment: Accidentally removed the .htaccess file.  Reverted it.