# Compilation from source Error while installing theme in Magento2

Tags: magento2, theme

I am trying to install a new free theme in my local system. After installing it, style sheet is showing 404 error in console. When I try to view the style sheet alone via browser, it shows the following error.

```
**mydomain/pub/static/version1491281875/frontend/Solwin/freego_child/en_US/css/styles-m.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**
```

I have compiled, deployed the static content and cleaned caches also via terminal. Also permissions are also given to pub and var folders.

Please can anyone say how to resolve this issue?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150418/static-content-is-not-loading-after-upgrade-to-2-1-3
you have similar problem

Comment: Take a look here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/162210/33057