# Magento2 calling assets in folder pub/static/versionXXXXXXX after static content deploy

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy

I'm running the command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` which exports all the assets in `pub/static` (creates folders: **_requirejs, adminhtml and frontend**), changes the deployed version in `deployed_version.txt`, and finishes with **0 errors**.

The problem is that my frontend is calling assets like:

```
$BASE_URL/pub/static/**version$DEPLOYED_VERSION**/frontend/... (e.g. http://local.estores.com/pub/static/version1503583668/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/calendar.css)
```

**instead of:**

```
$BASE_URL/pub/static/frontend/... (without the version folder).
```

Not sure why it's doing this, or how to change it. I upgraded and recompiled. The deploy process is creating the files, so I guess it's not a permissions thing.

[image]

Comment: take look here: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/static-file-signature.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an magento2 feature.

> magento2  used to overcome the browser cache for Static content.

There  will be file at **pub/static/.htaccess** which internally rewrite all

```
BASE_URL/pub/static/**version$DEPLOYED_VERSION**/frontend/
```

to

```
BASE_URL/pub/static/frontend/.
```

In your case, you have an issue with rewrite

[Static Content is not loading after upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150418/static-content-is-not-loading-after-upgrade)

Comment: Could have something to do with the PHP version? I downgraded to 5.6 since my local only has 7.0.0 (not accepted by Magento2, don't know why). I'll upgrade to 7.0.1 and see what happens. Thanks!