# HTTP403: PROHIBIDO

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I have a problem with the visualization of my store(www.tqueda.com) , they are not loading correctly the css and js files.

Apparently the error is per permissions. However, I have verified and the pub folder has 0777 and the static folder 0775. Execute the following commands but I did not succeed:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f es_PE
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

[image]

PD : My store is in mode : Default

thanks a lot  in advance

Comment: Hey Beto Javi, this "version1542081448" in your resources URLs look strange to me. http://www.tqueda.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/es_PE/requirejs-config.js (without "version1542081448") is loading ok. Does the resource at the given path actually exist?

Comment: You're right, there is no directory with that name. However, what exists is a file called "deployed_version.txt", inside this file it has the value: "1542081448", very strange. My local (test) installation has a .htaccess file inside "pub/static /". However, this does not exist in my store remote

Comment: see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190472/magento2-calling-assets-in-folder-pub-static-versionxxxxxxx-after-static-content, you need that .htaccess file, yes