# Issue regarding css/js file path in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3

When i am using this command :

> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

the adminhtml, frontend folders are generating in pub/static. But in website frontend css,js file paths are

> pub/static/version1552047239/frontend

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please check the Amit Bera answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190472/magento2-calling-assets-in-folder-pub-static-versionxxxxxxx-after-static-content

Comment: Yahh You can Prefer Amit Bera Answer  >> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190472/magento2-calling-assets-in-folder-pub-static-versionxxxxxxx-after-static-content